# Starcraft 2 Can't Click Connect

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been trying to get onto StarCraft 2 and it won't let me actually press the "Connect" button, it is grayed out, disabled; does anyone know how I can fix this? I have even tried reinstalling it, but that's no good either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your trying to go online if so.. Have you tried putting your full email address in as such:

> name@example.net

As shown in this picture :

[image]

Comment: omg thankyou i feel really stupid haha

Comment: @Tango - We all have our blonde moments ;)